# relation of numbers_ so called "power"

Tags: number-theory

I am dealing with programming exercise such that:

```
A number, a, is a power of b if it is divisible by b and a/b is a power of b. Write a
function called is_power that takes parameters a and b and returns True if a is a power of b. Note:
you will have to think about the base case.
```

---

**Question**:

Is there any pair of integers that is "power"?

What I am concerning about is if I take (8,2), which obviously looks power, however it recurse infinitely so there might be no integer which is power other than the pair consist of 1 and -1.

*posting here since my question actually not about programming.

Comment: Hint: $x^0=1{}$

Comment: @ParclyTaxel:  that is true mathematically.  OP has discovered that the spec does not support this and is asking for confirmation.  It would have been better to explain the recursion in the example, but I do not understand the downvote.  I think the recursion terminates when it looks at whether $1$ is a power of $b$ because $1$ is not divisible by $b$ (unless $b$ is $\pm 1$) and the program reports false all the time

Comment: Hmmm.  I think one needs to state explicitely that 1 is a power of any b.  Otherwise one will always reach a point where b does not divide and with only what is written one must return false.  No number recurses forever, that is not a concern but all terminate with some a that is not divisible but b.  If that number is 1 or -1 you want to return true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should unpack the definition for a small example.  In your example of $a=8, b=2$ it says $8$ is a power of $2$ if $8$ is divisible by $2$ and $8/2=4$ is a power of $2$, so we need to ask if $4$ is a power of $2$.  Then $4$ is a power of $2$ if $4$ is divisible by $2$ and $4/2=2$ is a power of $2$.  As you say, then you ask if $1$ is a power of $2$ and it is not because $1$ is not divisible by $2$.  That is the purpose of the hint about the base case.  The result is that if $b \neq \pm 1$ there are no powers of $b$.  I didn't check the $b=\pm 1$ case, but you are thinking correctly.  I agree with you that the spec as written is not correct for what one would think of as "Is $a$ a power of $b$?".

Answer (score 0):

Writing in Java:

```
public static boolean is_power(int a, int b) {
    if (a == 1)
        return true;
    else if (a < 0)
        return false;
    else if (a % b != 0)
        return false;
    else
        return is_power(a / b, b);
}
```

Comment: This is what OP said was not requested.  It is not a correct implementation of the spec, because it returns true if $a$ is $1$, but $1$ is not divisible by $b$.  OP was essentially asking if the spec is correct.

Comment: Whar do you mean by OP?

Comment: @jackerysmith:  original post(er), i.e. you

Answer (score 0):

"What I am concerning about is if I take (8,2), which obviously looks power, however it recurse infinitely so there might be no integer which is power other than the pair consist of 1 and -1."

That won't happen.

As long as the inputs, $a$ and $b$ are integers, $b \ne 1$, $a \ne 0$ and you have a procedure that accurately tells if a number is divisible, then the result of dividing will always be an integer that is smaller (absolute value).  There is always a finite  lowest integer before the test for divisibility fails.

Either you will have $a = b^n $ which will terminate with $a = 1$ and $b \not \mid 1$.  Or you will have $a = cb^n$ which will terminate with $a = c$ and $b \not \mid 1$.

You will always have $a > a/b > a/b^2 > .....  a \ge 1$ terminate (if $b \ne 1$).  You will never have $a > a/b > a/b^2 > ...... > a/b^i > ......$ infinitely.

But there are a few other things you should worry about.

1)If you input $b=1$ as a base, that *will* loop infinitely going nowhere.  $1$ will divide any $a$ and $a/1 = a$ and ...you repeat forever.

2)The other thing you must check for, is that when get down to $a=1$ the divisibility test will fail.  As $b\not \mid 1$.  The test terminates but you want it to return a *true* in this case.  Not *false*.

3) $a$ must never be $0$.

4) If you are allowing for negative $a$ or $b$ you may terminate at $a = -1$.  This will happen if $a = -b^n$ and it should return false.  (Note: this is different than $a = (-b)^n$ which will terminate at $a= 1$.)